# command to change directory into system file

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

all files in directory became locked as system files.  no user even root can change - so chmod does not work.  What command changes directories and recursive files to system files ?

this behavior only seemed to occur to source dir after rsync'ing directory to another drive.  makes sense as a risk for the destination folder not the source folder...thats why asking what command changes directory to system file.

Comment: *all files in directory became locked as system files* "locked as System files" is not a unix concept – it's absolutely not clear to me what you're referring to! "System Files" do not exist as special thing.

Comment: Indeed, there is no such thing as a "system file" in UNIX or Linux. Please add details to the question. I suggest as a minimum: Your operating system, a long directory listing of all those "system files", output of `df`,  `ls -ld` of that directory, your rsync command, and the error messages you get when attempting to chmod.

Comment: after your question was reopened, you can post the solution as an answer. thanks

Comment: @αғsнιη  idk - question was not reopened so the knowledge can not be shared - likely the question will resurface as more Windows installs are integrated deeper with bios, and  bios ultimately controls internal HDs - the issue will resurface for dual boot windows/linux users.  If question is reopened i will post the troubleshooting steps needed to identify the ambiguous linux error msgs generated by various linux flavors to the issue.

Comment: @t09 Feel free to provide your answer, would you still wish to do so.

Comment: @t09 NTFS or FAT can't change permissions for instance... So clarify where or on what (USB drive) with what file system e.g. FAT32...

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Answer (score 0):

Note: Answer originally added as an edit to the question, provided here as a community wiki as OP never posted it as a proper answer.

Maybe useful to anyone who has windows and linux running on the same computer.  Apparently a partial windows installation was the root cause (automatic install began as oem installs often do if no other boot media is recognized - but simply shutting off the system may likely duplicate this error).  The partial windows install later executed a drive user ownership corruption when triggered by rsync copying some directories from the system drive to an external drive.  The windows directories were not touched by rsync but some how windows did not like being prevented from install and now a linux mount of the harddrive with windows oem installed gives this message on a fresh debian 10 install:

```
user@debian:/home$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /home/hd1/
```

The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)

as mentioned above this error may differ from one linux flavor to another, but the root cause is still the same, and the trigger for the issue appears to be rsync copy process.  Thanx @Marcus Müller and @berndbausch  for pointing out the problem may not be linux although it was occurring within linux os